# org.hibernate.boot.spi.InFlightMetadataCollector$DuplicateSecondaryTableException after Spring boot Upgrade to 2.6.2 from 2.5.3

Tags: hibernate

Here is the error at start up - Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.spi.InFlightMetadataCollector$DuplicateSecondaryTableException: Table with that name [table_with_error] already associated with entity

Below is the class definition. This is working fine in 2.5.3.

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Entity(name = "table_with_error")
@IdClass(ClassHavingErrorKey.class)
public class ClassHavingError {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "col1")
    private String col1;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "col2")
    private String col2;
    @Column(name = "col3")
    private Integer col3;
    @Column(name = "col4")
    private Integer col4;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "table_with_error",
            joinColumns =  {@JoinColumn(name = "col2"), @JoinColumn(name = "col1")},
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "followup_col1"))
    private Question followup_col1
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [complete yet minimal example](/help/mcve) of the problem? A single entity isn't sufficient.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Can you see if this helps ? https://github.com/addepallimadhu/duplicateentityerror 
This also fails in spring boot version 2.5.x which I am still looking into

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - Now the issue can be clearly reproduced in the repo. If you switch to Spring boot version 2.5.12 the error goes away. The application should be run spring profiles active as pg. It requires a local postgres database instance. Hope this suffices as a complete  minimal example, please let me know.

Comment: I see a `DuplicateSecondaryTableException` with Spring Boot 2.5.12 and 2.6.8 so the example doesn't appear to reproduce the problem that you've described.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - Apologies for the inconvenience. To make it easier, have updated the default profile with the required application properties for reproducing the error. Have tested a few times it does eliminate the DuplicateSecondaryTableException for 2.5.12. Can you please pull the latest and try one more time?

Comment: Ok. I've now reproduced the behaviour that you described. It appears to be a change in behaviour or perhaps a regression in Hibernate 5.6.2.Final. The problem occurs with Spring Boot 2.5.12 if you upgrade Hibernate to 5.6.2.Final or later. It does not occur with 5.6.1.Final and earlier. You may want to raise this with the Hibernate team.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - Many thanks for your help. The issue has been reported https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15336

Comment: The issue does exist in Hibernate 5.6.2.Final or later. But it can be effectively resolved by simplifying the entity to use join column instead. The self join is unnecessary for this functionality. 
`       @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "col3", referencedColumnName = "followup_col1")
        private Question followup_col1
    }`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are using for the JoinTable the same name `table_with_error` used for the ClassHavingError entity table.